# Jquery event does not fire in local file, but does in fiddle

Tags: jquery

The code in a file on my computer

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script>
    $("#word").blur(function() {
alert('test');
$("#fo").innerHtml("focusout fired");}
);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id='word' contenteditable="true" title="Character Name"></div>
<div id='foo'>Foo</div>
</body>
```

The [Jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bE25/2/)

This code works (partly) in jfiddle, it will fire the event but not change the content of the foo div. So questions are:

- Why isn't it changing the content of the div in the fiddle.
- Why does the code on my local computer not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enclose your jquery code in `$(function(){})` for it to work on your local. 
Also, change `#fo` to `#foo`

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#word").blur(function () {
        $("#foo").html("focusout fired");
    });
});
</script>
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bE25/3/)

Also, note that i changed `innerHtml()` to `html()`

Comment: Oops, the foo thing is rather obvious on second look.

The other answer mentions putting it onLoad, what is the difference between $(document).ready(function() { and $(function(){?

Comment: @SpectralEdge - The latter is simply a shortcut for the former.

Comment: @SpectralEdge It is a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks. Will remember to check for doc load next time. Just starting to write js after doing just c# a while. Not used to what to look for.

Comment: It is a very common thing to get confused. Sometimes it is useful to see the chrome console to see if any errors show up.

Answer (score 1):

By default JSFiddle wraps your JS code in an `onload` handler - see the second drop-down on the left of the page under "Frameworks & Extentions" - which means your code isn't executed until after the whole page (all of your elements) have been loaded and parsed.

On your page you have not done that, so because your script block is at the top it runs before the rest of the page has been parsed and the browser doesn't yet know about the `"#word"` element.

That's why your fiddle works but your local project doesn't.

You can fix this by moving your script block to the end of the body or by wrapping the code in a document ready handler so that it will run after the rest of the page has been parsed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#word").blur(function () {
        alert('test');
        $("#foo").html("focusout fired");
    });
});
```

For most purposes jQuery's document ready is better than an `onload` handler because it will be triggered as soon as the page is parsed but without waiting for img or iframe elements to load.

Any good jQuery tutorial will explain use of [the `$(document).ready()` handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).